# Reverse SSH tunnelling through multiple firewalls

Tags: linux, ssh, firewall, tunnel

I want to access my work computer, which is behind a firewall, from my home computer.

As the work firewall blocks unexpected incoming connections, I would have to open a reverse SSH tunnel from my work computer to my home computer like so:
`ssh -R 12345:localhost:22 homeuser@homeip`
From my home computer, I could then use port 12345 to access the work computer:
`ssh -p 12345 workuser@localhost`

The problem is that this requires me to open holes in my home firewall and forward ports to my home computer.

This is my question:

**Is there any method by which I could have both machines meet each other half way?**
Assuming that I am at my home computer and a co-worker is at my work computer, and we both know each other's local IP (that the computer gets from the router) and internet IP (that the router gets from the ISP), **is there some way each of us could initiate an outgoing connection to the other?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you don't want to forward ports in routers, then you need some mutually accessible computer in between for both computers to connect to. (This could be a virtual machine such as those offered by Digital Ocean, or a web host that offers shell login, or you could dedicate something like a Raspberry Pi on your home network with SSH forwarded to it so it's always available.)

If you wanted to access port 22 on the remote computer:

```
ssh -R 12345:localhost:22 user@your.sshgateway.com
```

Then on the home computer:

```
ssh -L 2222:localhost:12345 user@your.sshgateway.com
```

Then you can connect to the remote computer with:

```
ssh -p 2222 workuser@localhost
```

Comment: I figured as much after reading about all of the difficulty other software has punching through NATs.The big problem with having a common accessible host is that all traffic now goes through that host rather than directly.

Comment: Sure, but as long as your gateway has fast upstream, how much of a problem is that really? I haven't had any real-world difficulties with this kind of setup.